# Problems getting stdout back from shell command in Python

Tags: bash, python-3.x, scripting, stdout, python-2.x

I have a line of Unix Shell code:

```
lsusb | sed -e 's/.*ID \([a-f0-9]\+:[a-f0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

I want to pass this to the shell from a script in Python and be able to catch the output in stdout as it would be displayed in the terminal after running that line of code.

However, I cannot get it to do it. I have tried:

- setting the variable I want to hold the output (x) equal to `os.system(lsusb | sed -e 's/.*ID \([a-f0-9]\+:[a-f0-9]\+\).*/\1/g')`
- setting `x` variable equal to `subprocess.Popen()` with all that mess being plugged in as a list and stdout being set to pipe and stderr and stdin being set to `DEVNULL`
- setting `x` equal to `subprocess.check_output()`, again with that whole line of code being passed in.
- setting `x` equal to the output of `run()`

I have also tried writing `lsusb` to a file and then passing that to `sed` instead of piping it. I have tried passing that entire line of code and setting all that equal to a variable in the shell and then setting the variable `x` equal to the shell variable. Finally, I have tried passing the output of this line of code to a file and reading the contents of that.

Everything I have tried will either give me:

- just 0
- these little square characters with 3 zeros and a 1 inside
- nothing

How can I get the data I am wanting passed to the `x` variable in a string format? This has been bugging me for a couple of days now and nothing is helping. If I need to use Python 3 that is okay, even though I prefer to use Python 2.

Thank you all for help! If you need any more information just ask and I will gladly edit them into the question here for all to see.

Thank you again!

Comment: Does the `sed` work on the command-line?

Comment: @cdarke yes. `sed` does work from the command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great answer about how to capture output from shell commands in Python at

[Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

In this case, I suspect you need to use

```
subprocess.check_output("lsusb | sed -e 's/.*ID \([a-f0-9]\+:[a-f0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'", shell=True)
```

You need the `shell=True` otherwise Python will interpret the string as a single command, rather than a pipeline.

Comment: I had already tried this. While it does actually give me output back, it is not the same output as is given in the shell.